# JS Infinite Scroll disable auto loading?

Tags: jquery, masonry

I am using the Infinite Scroll jQuery plugin from here:
http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/

```
    $grid.masonry({
        itemSelector: $grid.data('items'),
    });

    if ($grid.data('infinite'))
    {
        $grid.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: $grid.data('nav'),
            nextSelector: $grid.data('next'),
            itemSelector: ".articleItem"
        }, function( newElements ) {
            var $newElems = $( newElements );
            $grid.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });
    }
```

It works very well. However, there is one small change I want to make to it. Right now, whenever I scroll down, it will auto load the next page. I only want it to auto load the first TWO extra pages, and then after that, PAUSE auto loading and require the user to click a button in order to resume auto loading.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: what about the custom trigger functionality? Seems like what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the website you linked:

> Custom trigger, non-automatic. Twitter-style In 1.4 you can trigger
>   the loading of the next page of content at will. You’ll first unbind
>   the default behavior. And then trigger the next pull whenever you
>   like..

```
 // unbind normal behavior. needs to occur after normal infinite scroll
 setup. $(window).unbind('.infscr'); // call this whenever you want to
 retrieve the next page of content // likely this would go in a click
 handler of some sort $(document).trigger('retrieve.infscr'); Demo of
 the triggered infinite scroll functionality.
```

> How does it work? There is a little known feature in the .load()
>   method that lets you specify the CSS selector of the html you want to
>   include. jQuery will load in any local URL, then parse the html and
>   grab only the elements you’ve defined with your selector. This allows
>   for some pretty fun shit: client-side transclusions (a la purple
>   include) ; and some really kickass shit when you combo it with a local
>   php proxy.
>
> This is really the meat of the code:

```
 // load all post divs from page 2 into an off-DOM div $('
 ').load('/page/2/ #content div.post',function(){ 
     $(this).appendTo('#content');    // once they're loaded, append them to our content area });
```

> So it basically leverages that load()
>   method at its core. It’s basically scraping your existing page
>   structure, which means you don’t need to code any custom backend stuff
>   to enable this functionality! Booyah, right?

Seems to me like you could detect the first 2 page loads and then halt it using the method to unbind normal behavior (first code block) and then set it back up on some event (second code block)